# Angular dynamic remove filter from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in staff | profAndDr">
```

And a custom filter that shows people with title "Dr." and "Prof." only:

```
app.filter('profAndDr', function() {
return function(input) {
    var out = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(title) {
        if (title.title === 'PROF.'||title.title==='DR.') {
            out.push(title)
        }
    })
return out;
}
```

I need to add a checkbox that does show people with title "Prof. Amaritos" if checked. So, basically I need to remove my filter from ng-repeat if checked.

Link to [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLqXwg?editors=1010)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variables into your filter and then use this to determine if your checkbox is checked.

e.g.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in staff | profAndDr: isChecked">
```

Then

```
app.filter('profAndDr', function() {
    return function(input, isChecked) {
        var out = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function(title) {
            if (title.title === 'PROF.' || title.title==='DR.' || (isChecked && [othercondition])) {
                out.push(title)
            }
        })
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write additional `ng-repeat` without filter but its bad practice. I suggest you to pass true/false flag to filter that  should return `input` as is.

*HTML*

```
<div ng-app="staffApp">
    <div ng-controller="StaffListCtrl">
    <label for="amaritos">Show Amaritos</label>
    <input id="amaritos" type="checkbox" ng-model="showFlag">
    <hr />
    <div 
            ng-cloak 
            ng-repeat="user in staff | profAndDr:showFlag">
      {{user.title}} {{user.first}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*filter*

```
phonecatApp.filter('profAndDr', function() {
    return function(input) {
        var out = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function(title) {
            if (title.title === 'PROF.'||title.title==='DR.') {
                out.push(title)
            }
        })
    return out;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value of the checkbox as a parameter to your filter. In case you want to show everything, just return the original input.

```
app.filter('profAndDr', function() {
  return function(input, showAmaritos) {
    if (showAmaritos) {
      return input;
    }
    var out = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(title) {
        if (title.title === 'PROF.'||title.title==='DR.') {
            out.push(title)
        }
    });
    return out;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="amaritos" ng-model="showAmaritos" type="checkbox">

<div ng-repeat="user in staff | profAndDr:showAmaritos">
```

See [improved codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBwaxP?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

updated js

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('staffApp', []);

"use strict";

 phonecatApp.controller('StaffListCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function         ($scope) {
 $scope.title=false;
 $scope.staff = [
{
  "first": "POZIK",
      "last": "GOLDSMITH",
      "title": "PROF."
},
{
  "first": "LOSHOK",
      "last": "GALIMIY",
      "title": "DR."
},
{
  "first": "SHMOK",
      "last": "GOLDSMITH",
      "title": "PROF. AMARITOS"
},
```

]
        }])

```
phonecatApp.filter('profAndDr', function() {
return function(input,test) {
    var out = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(title) {
    if(test == false){
        if (title.title === 'PROF.'||title.title==='DR.') {
            out.push(title)
        }

    }
     else if(test == true){
        if (title.title === 'PROF. AMARITOS') {
            out.push(title)
        }
      }
    })
return out;
}
```

});

and in your html

```
<input id="amaritos" type="checkbox" ng-model='title'>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can intercept the value of your inputs by assigning them a variable in an `ng-model` property. You can then add condition to your filter to do different things based on the value of your inputs.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYmpvZ

Hope this helps.